# Multible combining diacritics

Tags: positioning, combine

How can I reproduce `ā́` in plain (la)tex? `\'{{\=a}` doesn't work for me, it places the outer diacritic in front of the a-overbar.

Comment: Is it for use in maths formulæ?

Comment: No, for text mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're gonna work with pdfLaTeX, use `tipa` (it defines a lot of combinations for linguistic and philological purposes). [Manual here.](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb17-2/tb51rei.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textipa{\'=a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't be sure pdfLaTeX will be available, but if no other options exist, I will mark this as the answer

Comment: pdfLaTeX is the LaTeX we use by default along with LaTeX. The main difference is the output. LaTeX outputs a .dvi file and pdfLaTeX outputs a .pdf files. In most cases packages do the same thing with both engines.

Comment: I'm working on a plugin that exports bibtex from zotero -- I cannot control what engine will be used so I'm looking for the most general solution. But if this is the only way, that is the most general solution :)

Comment: Someone suggested covington off-site -- do you know how that would compare?

Comment: I see that `\textipa{\'=a}` works but `\textipa{\='a}` does not -- the manual doesn't indicate what order these should be in, do you know whether I can find this information?

Comment: Diacritic macros are predefined in `tipa`, so it's logical some combinations don't work.

Comment: I've just read the manual of `covington`. It's nice for more linguistic things, such as glosses. But if you only need symbols, `tipa` is preferable, I think.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the list that tipa predefines?

Comment: Oh wait, they're listed individually in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give pdftex a bit of help and manual positioning

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

1 \'{{\=a}} 

\def\zz#1{\={#1}\llap{\raisebox{.5ex}{\'{}}}}

2 \zz{a}



\end{document}
```